# Background image position 50% not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I'm looking for a solution to get a background image in the middle. This doesn't work in Safari!?

CSS:

```
.loader
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8) url('bilderGuide/bilderLayout/ajax-loader.gif') no-    repeat 50%;
z-index: 10;
display: none;
}

#buildingGalleryContainer 
{
width: 65%;
height: auto;
float: left;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="buildingGalleryContainer">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <img src="bilderGuide/bilder-byggnader-stora/gemini-1.jpg" alt="Bild på Gemini" id="mainImage" class="buildingGalleryContainer"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is no-repeat :

```
.loader {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8) url('bilderGuide/bilderLayout/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat 50%;
   z-index: 10;
   display: none;
}
```

or try:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
background-image: url('bilderGuide/bilderLayout/ajax-loader.gif') ;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 50%  50%;
```

**SCREEN on safari Version 7.0.2 (9537.74.9)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There is a no-repeat, but there must be a paste error here. The second solution isn't working. I have to check my code and come back.

Comment: ok and please provide the browser version  http://jsfiddle.net/pyXBN/  and this is the fullscreen http://jsfiddle.net/pyXBN/embedded/result/ working on safari

Comment: I discovered that I also had a div for a menu inside the buildingGalleryContainer div. I created a new div for the image and used position relative to that div. Now it's looking better. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100% 126% !important;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 550px;
background-position: bottom right !important;
background-position-x: 0 !important;
background-position-y: 0px !important;

http://122.180.31.14/staging/htm/m2/2017/oct/RNP/about.html
check on .tbs.newss classes
this will work in all browsers.
```